# Is there a way to view a list of tags?

Tags: support, tagging

I am relatively new to this site and recently earned editing privileges including editing tags in questions. I would like to improve questions by adding relevant tags but the issue that I have is that I do not know what tags are available to add.

I'm aware of the Tag link and the page that shows the tags in informational boxes. The problem is that this list is currently 24 pages long and I don't have time or the energy to scan all the way through. Nor is my memory good enough to memorize the list. I could create my own list but due to the layout, I would have to manually select and then cut and paste each tag.

I've looked over the site, reviewed the FAQ, and searched as best as I am able and have not been able to find an answer. Is there a way to view or easily create a list of tags?

[image]

Comment: [There's a SEDE query for that](https://data.stackexchange.com/diy/query/1210462).